# Vertically align span with image inside div

Tags: html, css

Please see `fiddle` and do not change id "darko" I need it as it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/2PSNN/4/

Comment: for class name using point for name

Comment: There is no class having name `darko` in your css, they are `IDs`

Comment: Put an equal sign (=)

Comment: Asking a question with little details and requirements, and then down-voting unwanted answers (which really gives solution) because of his own fault - nice

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#darko {
text-align: center;
vertical-align : middle;
border: 2px solid red;
}
#darko > * {
vertical-align : middle;
}
#darko1 {
margin: auto 0;
border: 2px solid green;
display: inline-block;
}
#darko2 {
margin: auto 0;
border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2PSNN/3/

Comment: Well at least in first place, if you just said it in your question it would not be removed. I answered based on the title of your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/C6pf7/)**

```
#darko img{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: You want the text over the image or next to it? In your updated fiddle you are assigning a `float:left` to `#darko1`. If you remove it wouldn't it be fine?